# Why wont iTunes detect my new iPhone 4S?

Tags: itunes, iphone, mobile-device-management

When I connect my iPhone 4S to my computer (OSX v 10.4.11), iTunes (9.2  61) does not detect the device. The phone displays the green battery meter indicating it's charging, System Profiler detects an "iPhone" connected to the USB bus, and iphoto automatically opens and prompts me to import new photos.

The phone also does not appear in my devices.

I have tried:

- using a different sync cable
- using a different USB port
- restarting the phone
- restarting the computer
- opening "image capture" and selecting "itunes" as the default application to open when "camera" is connected.

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade to OSX 10.5.8 and iTunes 10.5 (at a minimum) for iTunes to recognize your iPhone 4S...

See the [iPhone 4S System Requirements](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html) for details...